# Converting from letters to binary to decimal and finally to char

Tags: c

So I have this code that is getting user input, char by char (not using char arrays), and what should happen is every 7 letters corresponds to a letter, each letter in the 7 letters is a 1 or a 0, depending on if the ascii value of that letter is even or odd (even for 0s , odd for 1s).

For Example: "GCJLLBI" = "1100001", which converted to decimal = 97, which is the ascii code for 'a'.
So if the user enters "GCJLLBI" then the program needs to convert that into binary, then to decimal, which will then be printed using %c and the decimal value.
**Must not use arrays** I am trying to do this with only primitives, no abstract data types or arrays.
Here's the code I got so far:

```
/** given a binary number, convert to decimal. */
int binToDec(int binary) 
{
    int decimal = 0, i = 1, remainder;

    /* Iterate until number becomes zero */
    while (binary != 0)
    {
        remainder = binary % 10;
        decimal = decimal + remainder * i;
        i = i * 2;
        binary = binary / 10;
    }

    return decimal;
}

/* Decodes text.*/
int decode(void) {
    char ch;
    printf("? ");
    discardToEOL(); /*Discards any newlines from previous. */
    /*Get Input */
    do {
        scanf("%c", &ch);
    if (ch >= 0 && ch <= 128 && ch != 10) {
        //Send each char to get converted 
        //to binary and then convert binary to ddecimal, 
        //then display as char.

    }
    } while(ch != '\n');
    printf("\n");   
}
```

***So really what I need help with and don't understand is if the user enters like 21 characters, those are being entered char by char and not into an array, how do I parse those into groups of 7, and then convert them to binary based on even or odd value of them?***

Comment: Something like `int b = 0; for (i=0; i<7; i++) { int ch = fgetchar(); b = b*2 + (ch&1); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read one character at a time from the input stream, and keep a running tally of the value for the current character to be printed.

The code below starts by initializing `value` to 64, and adding this to the total value for the current printing character if the value of the input character is odd. Then `value` is reduced, and the loop continues. When `value` reaches zero, the current printing character associated with the previous group of input characters is printed, and `value` and `cur_sum` are reset. The loop continues until a newline or end-of-file is reached. After the loop exits, there should be one character left to print (the character associated with the input preceding the `\n`). If `value` is non-zero at this point, then the number of input characters was not a multiple of 7, and an error message is printed; otherwise the final character is printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int value = 64;
    int cur_sum = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        if (value == 0) {
            putchar(cur_sum);
            value = 64;
            cur_sum = 0;
        }
        cur_sum += (value * (c % 2));
        value /= 2;
    }

    if (value) {
        putchar('\n');
        puts("Input format error");
    } else {
        putchar(cur_sum);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample interaction:

```
GJLIBBLGCJBIBIGCJIIBBGCJIIBBGCJICICJGJLLBBGCIJGCIGCJICICGCIJLIBGCJGCJJGCJLIBBJGLLBBI
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add some kind of counter and an accumulator (sum). The problem here is the pow(). Since it accepts double. You could also make your own pow function that accepts integers and multiplies them multiple times. (Sorry for my answers, first answer in stackoverflow)

```
int count = 0; //add a counter here
int sum = 0;
do {
    scanf("%c", &ch);
if (ch >= 0 && ch <= 128 && ch != 10) {
    //Send each char to get converted 
    //to binary and then convert binary to ddecimal, 

    sum += pow(2,count) * convertedBinaryNumber;
    //convertedBinaryNumber either 1 or 0

    count++;
    if(count == 7){
         count == 0;
         //print sum here to ascii
         sum = 0;
    }

    }
} while(ch != '\n');
```

Comment: Uhm, no that just prints every sixth character. So for example if a person enters the following in one line "GCJLLBI" and then presses enter, the program should then take that whole series of chars, convert each letter to a 1 or a 0 depending on if the ASCII value is even or odd, THEN convert that whole 7 bit binary string into a decimal, then print decimal.

Comment: So in place of "send each char to get converted", accumulate the bits, and in place of "display as char", display the accumulator.

Comment: Ok so i'm thinking a better way would be under my first if statement, to check if each letter is even or odd, and add a 0 or 1 to an int (to represent binary number), then after 7 chars, send the int to my bin to dec converter and reset the binary to 0 and start again until EOL. But I am not sure how to add 1 and 0 to my binary number as it goes along.